# How to insert multiple rows at once from R to Oracle

Tags: sql, r, oracle

I am trying to insert multiple rows from R to Oracle. For this we need to form a query like

```
INSERT ALL
     INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (ABC',1,'30-12-15', '30-12-15',89)
     INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (ABC',2,'30-12-15', '31-12-15',96)
     INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (ABC',3,'30-12-15', '03-01-16',92)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

I thought paste function would work here. But when I am using paste function, it's working like this

```
     temp_df <- data.frame(col1=c(rep('ABC',3)), col2=c(1,2,3), col3=rep('30-12-15',3), 
                        col4=c('30-12-15','31-12-15','03-01-16'), col5=c(89,96,92))

    > qry <- paste("INSERT ALL ", rep("INTO mytable  (",3), 
           rep(paste(names(temp_df), collapse = ", "),3), 
           rep(") VALUES ", 3), 
           gsub('c','',(data.table(t(temp_df))[,paste(.SD,collapse=', ')])), 
           " SELECT * FROM dual", sep="")

    > cat(qry)


    INSERT ALL INTO mytable  (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
        VALUES ("ABC", "1", "30-12-15", "30-12-15", "89"), 
               ("ABC", "2", "30-12-15", "31-12-15", "96"), 
               ("ABC", "3", "30-12-15", "03-01-16", "92") SELECT * FROM dual 
    INSERT ALL INTO mytable  (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
        VALUES ("ABC", "1", "30-12-15", "30-12-15", "89"), 
               ("ABC", "2", "30-12-15", "31-12-15", "96"), 
               ("ABC", "3", "30-12-15", "03-01-16", "92") SELECT * FROM dual 
    INSERT ALL INTO mytable  (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
        VALUES ("ABC", "1", "30-12-15", "30-12-15", "89"), 
               ("ABC", "2", "30-12-15", "31-12-15", "96"), 
               ("ABC", "3", "30-12-15", "03-01-16", "92") SELECT * FROM dual
```

But I need output like

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO mytable  (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
           VALUES ("ABC", "1", "30-12-15", "30-12-15", "89")
    INTO mytable  (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
           VALUES ("ABC", "2", "30-12-15", "31-12-15", "96")
    INTO mytable  (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
           VALUES ("ABC", "3", "30-12-15", "03-01-16", "92") 
SELECT * FROM dual
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest way to do it is create first something like:
`qr1<-"INSERT ALL"`

and then the query as you have done up there without the `INSERT ALL`, and finally pasting them togheter to create the final query.

Comment: It doesn't work here. Because, in my case I have to use a for loop for calculating certain values and at the end of each for loop, I will get a data frame which I need to insert into Oracle. So each time the number of rows to be inserted is dynamic. The actual problem occurs here. I need "VALUES" in front of each tuple and also "INSERT INTO mytable" in front of each column names tuple. But it's not happening here.